# Why was this edit rejected despite incorrect spelling being improved?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

The guy submitting the correction suggestion is indeed right. Why was it rejected?

[image]

Comment: Why do you post an image instead of a link to the suggestion? This way, we need to find the suggested edit before we can evaluate it at all...

Comment: *"This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit"* is why; it was rejected by the Community user, not the reviewers. What is unclear?

Comment: @Deduplicator Because I didn't know that you could do that. How do you get the link to the actual edit suggestion that ensures that you see exactly the same as I do?

Comment: The browsers address bar if you look at the suggestion, your profile if you submitted it (activity>all actions>suggestions), or your profile if you reviewed it (activity>all actions>reviews).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Aha, now I understand. The unclear part was what that meant in practice. I believe that I corrected the typo myself but then forgot or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was rejected by you.

The suggestion was in the [suggested edits queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10649591) when you visited your own question and made that [same edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34413150/revisions), thereby completing the review task. Edits of OP's always take precedence over suggested edits. It doesn't matter if your revision is similar to the one suggested. It is much easier to simply invalidate the review task. The Community user takes the blame.